# Food allergy and weight loss

Tags: allergy, allergen

I have red a lot of articles about excluding products that causes allergy can help people lose weight. But is it possible that having allergy on some products and eating them often could result in not being able to gain weight?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Welcome to this site @istoby. Please read the comments of Chris above. Also I'd advice to change the title into a real question such as "Can a food allergy result in weight gaining difficulties?"